# get the text inside an element above another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, traversal

I have the code below which renders a box with some information inside it. I need to get the text of some of the divs above the button which the user will click in order to get the information. I can't use ids as the rest of the page will have the same code again and again with different text.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dummy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab">
    <div class="bg-light px-3 my-2">                          
        <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-1 my-2">
            <span class="display-4 ws_day"><strong>04</strong></span>
            <br>
            <span class="ws_month"><strong>Jan</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-lg-1 my-2">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-2 my-2">
            <span><strong>Lorem</strong></span>
            <br>
            <span class="ws_time">6pm</span>
            <br>
            <span class="ws_timezone">(GTM+12:00)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 my-2">
            <span class="h5 ws_title"><strong>Title</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-2 my-2">
            <span><strong>Ipsum</strong></span>
            <br>
            <span><strong>Ipsium</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-2 my-2">
            <a class="dec-none" role="button">
                <button class="btn btn-orange buttonClick" style="white-space: normal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Button</button>
            </a>
        </div>
        </div>                          
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".buttonClick").on("click", function(){
    var title = $(this).closest("div span").find(".ws_title").text());          
 });
```

I have tried multiple combinations using the jQuery documentation but with no luck.

Is it even possible to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the extra `)` in the JS causing a syntax error, the issue is due to `closest('div span')`. You need to give a selector to `closest()` which is the nearest parent of *both* elements. As such `closest('.row')` will work, given the HTML in your example.

Also note that you cannot nest clickable elements in HTML as it's invalid. As such I removed the `a` which wrapped the `button`.

```js
$(".buttonClick").on("click", function() {
  var title = $(this).closest(".row").find(".ws_title").text();
  console.log(title);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="dummy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab">
    <div class="bg-light px-3 my-2">
      <div class="row align-items-center text-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 my-2">
          <span class="h5 ws_title"><strong>Title</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-2 my-2">
          <button class="btn btn-orange buttonClick" style="white-space: normal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Button</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I removed the non-relevant parts of your HTML in the example above to make it shorter.

Comment: I see, this would work except that inside the .pane-tab I will have more than one elements with the same classes... what I need exactly is to find the 1st element above the button which match the class given

Comment: Try `.row` instead. Failing that you'll need to add another element which contains each group and target that instead

Comment: .bg-light isn't a class for styling the background?

Comment: It may well be, but you can still use it to select elements via JS. I think `.row` would be better, though.

Comment: I see, I see... thanks a lot... I will try it now and if it works I will accept your answer :)